# Why do I get "str" object has no attribute "readlines" error when running this "read from file" code?

Tags: python, file, bioinformatics, readlines

So, I have a file and I need to read in from the columns of the file. The column contains frequency of genes as floats. The number of the column to be read in is `column_number` variable. Then, all of the floats (there are only floats in the column) in that column should be appended to a list. So far I have gotten this far:

```
def read_column(file_name, column_number):
lines = file_name.readlines()
floats = []
for x in lines:
    floats.append(x.split(" ")[column_number])
return floats
```

The file is passed in as an argument and does not need to be opened, since the test program creates and opens a temporary file with the genetic frequencies in it.

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "file is passed in as an argument" Your function expects a ``file_name``. Do you actually pass in a file or just its name/path?

Comment: I *recommend* passing the file. Let the caller open the file; this make `read_column` easier to test because it will work with *any* file-like object, not just one provided by the `open` function.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the parameter name, the function expects a file-like object, not the name of a file that you would then need to open.

```
with open(my_file_name) as f:
    x = read_column(f, 3)
```

This is preferable to redefining the function to take a filename that you open, because your file will work with *any* file-like object (e.g., `io.StringIO`), making it easier to test.

In fact, you can make a simple change that will make the function both more memory-efficient (by not reading the entire file into memory at once) *and*  able to work with *any* iterable (like a `list`), not just a file-like object.

```
def read_column(itr, column_number):
    floats = []
    for x in itr:
        floats.append(x.split(" ")[column_number])
    return floats
```